# How to pass two arguments to a UIButtons target method in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, addtarget

In my code I've to pass two arguments to targetMethod `printMethod`, I can pass the button.tag as one argument and how to pass the other argument?

Please Give an Example.

**My code:**

```
 button.tag = indexPath.row;
 secondArgument = indexPath.section;
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(printMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(IBAction)printMethod:(UIButton*)sender{
    NSLog(@"%d%d",sender.tag,//SecondArgument);
}
```

Comment: You can't. What you can do is subclass UIButton, and give him properties (indexPath, otherDataToShare).

Comment: An IBAction method only accepts a single argument; the sender

Comment: What's your second argument?

Comment: you can use 'CALayer' of the UI object to save data in it. Like [layer setValue:value forKey@"Key"]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `indexPath` on button action then try something like this.

```
-(IBAction)printMethod:(UIButton*)sender{

     CGPoint point = [sender.superview convertPoint:sender.center toView:self.tableView];
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
     if (indexPath) {
          NSLog(@"Section - %ld Row - %ld",deleteIndexPath.section, deleteIndexPath.row);
     }
}
```

Comment: but the comment of  Arpit B Parekh is better than your answer, where you can even pass the objects as arguments;

Comment: @AMIamitekh I have never try that approach so doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Just subclass `UIButton` and add properties in that class which you want to pass as parameter.

then you can assess it by instance of that button. for example,

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomFileCapturebutton : UIButton

@property int maxNumberOfFilesAllow;
@property NSString *fileType;

@end
```

then create instance of `CustomFileCapturebutton` and create action something like,

```
-(void)captureClick : (CustomFileCapturebutton*)sender{

    // you can use your properties here like



   NSLog (@"%@",sender.fileType);

 }
```

you can set that properties at that time when you `addtarget` on button like,

```
  CustomFileCapturebutton *btn = [[CustomFileCapturebutton alloc]init];

  btn.frame = yourFrame;

   [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(captureClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  btn.fileType = @"png";   // set properties here
```

Answer (score 1):

Try **accessibilityIdentifier** for pass second argument to button

```
button.accessibilityIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.section)];
```